# Get employees for each sub department and department with Streams,

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list of employees. I need to get list of employee ids for each department and subdepartment,

```
class Employee{
    int id;
    String name;
    String department;
    String subDepartment;
}
```

I checked many tutorials and tried but no luck.

```
employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(empl->empl.getDepartment(), // get sub-departmets and empId list for each sub-departmets));
```

I need result like,

```
{Dept1={subDept1=[1, 2], subDept2=[3, 4, 5]}
```

Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupBy`,

```
employeeList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
                 Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getSubDepartment,
                         Collectors.mapping(Employee::getId, toList()))));
```